# How to use cookie into specific show/hide javascript header. Live example included

Tags: php, javascript

With the help of [Th0rndike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1251715/th0rndike) & [Pranav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/553098/pranav), I have make a show/hide header on my site. What I want to do next, is to set a cookie on user's side, so next time this user browses my site, header remains in it's last condition. Live example, on comment below.

I have no idea about cookies, except the very basic stuff, so please, if you have the kindness, be a little bit explanatory to me!!! :)

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) Have you [looked up some cookie tutorials for JavaScript](https://www.google.nl/search?q=javascript+cookie+tutorial+-w3schools)?

Comment: @Cerbrus: I tried something like this http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp but I do something wrong, I don't know. As I said I have no idea about cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function setCookie(h,a,f){
try{
document.cookie=escape(h)+"="+escape(a)+(f?"; expires=Thu, 31 Dec 2020 23:59:59 GMT":"")+";
path=/";return true;
}catch(c){
alert(c.Message);
}
return false;
}
```

Try this function 
i have created its sets session cookie if you pass parameter to this function
like this :- `setCookie('your key','your value',false);`

There are two types of cookie one is session and other is persistent cookie,
session cookies expires after a particular session and persistent cookie persist for the amount of time written in your function.

For persistent cookie pass parameter as such `setCookie('your key','your value',true);`

this is function to get cookie

```
function getCookie(m){
    try{
          var f=m+"=";
          var l=document.cookie;
          var b=-1;
          var a=-1;
            if(l.length>0){
                b=l.indexOf(f);

                if(b>-1){
                    b+=f.length;
                    a=l.indexOf(";",b);
                    a=((a==-1)?l.length:a);
                     g=unescape(l.substring(b,a));
                }
            }
    }catch(h){
    alert(h.Message);
    }
    return g;
}
```

pass only the key name of cookie as this :- getCookie('your key name');

Comment: If you want that your persistent cookie to be set so whenever any user will serve from that machines particular browser on which cookie is set than just put this two function into your script and call it on window.onload =function(){
var val = getCookie('your key name');
if(val == ''){
setCookie('your key','your value',true);
//do whatever you want
}else{
//do whatever you want }

Comment: I think I got it... Give me some minutes to do my tests and I'll be back to accept you answer!!! Really thank you for your time!!! :)